# A boundary for integrals of eigenfunctions over geodesics?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact hyperbolic surface, and $\gamma$ a closed geodesic on it. 
Consider the  integral 
$$\int_\gamma f(x)\, dl(x)$$
where $f$ is a (normalized)  Laplace eigenfunction on $X$.  Intuitively, if  the length $l$ of $\gamma$ is large while  the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is moderate, then one would  expect  this integral to be small.  Did anyone found bounds for  this integral (in terms of $l$  and $\lambda$)?

Comment: A long geodesic can spend entire life at the set where $f$ is close to its maximum. Also, you may go around fix geodesic many times, so increasing the length does not give a better estimate.